# Output Dimensions of convolution in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

The size of my input images are 68 x 224 x 3 (HxWxC), and the first `Conv2d` layer is defined as

`conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 16, stride=4, kernel_size=(9,9))`.

Why is the size of the output feature volume 16 x 15 x 54? I get that there are 16 filters, so there is a 16 in the front, but if I use `[(W−K+2P)/S]+1` to calculate dimensions, the dimensions are not divisible.

Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The calculation of feature maps is `[(W−K+2P)/S]+1` and here `[]` brackets means floor division. In your example padding is `zero`, so the calculation is `[(68-9+2*0)/4]+1 ->[14.75]=14 -> [14.75]+1 = 15` and `[(224-9+2*0)/4]+1 -> [53.75]=53 -> [53.75]+1 = 54`.

```py
import torch

conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 16, stride=4, kernel_size=(9,9))
input = torch.rand(1, 3, 68, 224)

print(conv1(input).shape)
# torch.Size([1, 16, 15, 54])
```

You may see different formulas too calculate feature maps.

In **PyTorch**:
[image]

In general, you may see this:

[image]

**However the result of both cases are the same**

Comment: Just  to save some basic mental calculation to anyone wondering how are the two formulas given here the same: eg. dilation is 1 by default so when you multiply -1*(kernel_size -1) then you get (-kernel_size +1) so the +1 cancels out with the one outside the parenthesis and you get the formula below.

Answer (score 1):

Was having same kind of inconvenience estimating output size of tensor after convolutional layer. Check out a helper function I implemented at https://github.com/tuttelikz/conv_output_size.

Example:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from conv_output_size import conv2d_output_size

c_i, c_o = 3, 16
k, s, p = 3, 2, 1

sample_2d_tensor = torch.ones((c_i, 64, 64))
c2d = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=c_i, out_channels=c_o, kernel_size=k,
                stride=s, padding=p)

output_size = conv2d_output_size(
    sample_2d_tensor.shape, out_channels=c_o, kernel_size=k, stride=s, padding=p)

print("After conv2d")
print("Dummy input size:", sample_2d_tensor.shape)
print("Calculated output size:", output_size)
print("Real output size:", c2d(sample_2d_tensor).detach().numpy().shape")

>>> After conv2d
>>> Dummy input size: torch.Size([3, 64, 64])
>>> Calculated output size: (16, 32, 32)
>>> Real output size: (16, 32, 32)
```